# Checkbox overlap in dropdown

Tags: css, aurelia

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRqbl.jpg)

First line I have dropdown.

Second line I have toggle checkbox.

When I open dropdown toggle checkbox overlapping dropdown.

How to avoid. Immediate response would helpful

```
    <div class="flex-row--margin-10 flex-columns ${isFromPendingProjects ?'':'display-column'}">         
        <div class="${isFromPendingProjects ?'flex-row__col-34':'menu-column'}">
            <io-dropdown value.bind="lobId" change.delegate="enableDisableCreateBtn()" class="${isFromPendingProjects ?'width-95':'width-100'}">
                <io-input type="text" placeholder="Line of Business" class="width-100" value.bind="lobText"></io-input>
                <io-dropdown-item repeat.for="option of iLOBs" value.bind="option.LobId">${option.LobName}</io-dropdown-item>
            </io-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
            <br />
    <div class="${isFromPendingProjects ?'flex-row__col-34':'menu-column'}" style="width:100%">
        <div>
            <span style="font-size:16px">Administrative Claims Data</span>
            <span class="highlight-text">
                <img src="../images/info.svg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
                     i18n="[title]projectDetail.tooltipIntegrateClaimsData" style="margin-top:-4px" />
            </span>
            <label class="switch switch-color" style="width:45px; display: inline">
                <input type="checkbox" checked.bind="IntegrateClaimsData" change.delegate="enableDisableCreateBtn()" />
                <span class="toggleSlider round" style="margin-top:-5px;"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Include your code in your question.

Comment: Hi added code. please check

Comment: Screenshot also added in my question. please check and respond asap

Answer (score 1):

You should add z-index css property to your drop-down to fix this issue.
you have limited code displayed here, but looking at the available data, adding z-index: 1; to checkbox and z-index: 2; to drop-down section should fix the issue.